# Como hacer una consulta select dentro de otro select en mysql

Tags: mysql, funciones, select

estoy tratando de seleccionar datos  de una tabla, pero en una de sus columnas quiero que cuente el total de dias asistidos de acuerdo a cada trabajador (los dias asistidos estan en otra tabla llamada asistencia, estan unidas por el FK_contrato_cod).
Hice mi consulta pero como la tablas tienen muchos registros se genera un problema con las cookies :(
Mi consulta está asi:

```
SELECT
CONCAT_WS(' ',t.trab_apellidopate, t.trab_apellidomate, t.trab_nombre)as trabajador,
(SELECT COUNT(a.asistencia_dias) FROM asistencia a WHERE a.contrato_cod = c.contrato_codigo)
FROM contrato c
INNER JOIN trabajador t ON c.trabajador_cod = t.trabajador_cod
WHERE c.contrato_estatus = 'VIGENTE'
```

Comment: genera in problema con que? que cookies????

Comment: Solo quitale el select y deja `COUNT(a.asistencia_dias)`

Comment: No hay _cookies_ en la base de datos, creo que es mejor que expliques con mayor detalle cuál es el problema que se presenta, porque, el que sea, probablemente no tiene nada que ver con cookies, y si tiene que ver con ellas, probablemente no tenga nada que ver con la consulta.

Comment: @jachguate es que cuando ejecuto la consulta carga y carga pero nunca salen resultados y luego de eso ya no puedo entrar a la bd, cuando borro las cookies del navegador recien puedo volver a ingresar a la bd

Comment: ¿cuántas filas hay en cada una de las tablas?, ¿qué versión de mySQL estás utilizando?